# netbeans 7 groovy editor

Tags: netbeans, groovy

I've been trying out Netbeans 7 for its native groovy support, and one thing that seems to be a problem is automatically generated getters for boolean members using the isXXX syntax.

I have a groovy class

```
class MyClass {
   boolean finished
}
```

From my Java code, I should be able to call either isFinished or getFinished as follows:

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass();
System.out.println(mc.isFinished());
System.out.println(mc.getFinished());
```

However, the groovy editor within netbeans tells me that `mc.isFinished` cannot be found (but it compiles fine in maven and eclipse). I've filed a bug with netbeans, but this seems like a major issue with the netbeans editor. Has anyone had this problem before and/or know if there is a way to work around it?

thanks,
Jeff

Comment: According to the Java beans standard, the name of a boolean accessor is different for a Boolean and a boolean. In one case it's getProperty and in the other it's isProperty. This is so ridiculous that I struggle to believe it myself, but apparently it's true.

Comment: Really? I wasn't aware of that...that does seem a bit silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last time I looked, the Groovy support in Netbeans was stuck at Groovy v1.6.4.

This is over 2 years old :-(

I have heard rumours that it is set to improve in the future, but at the time of writing this, if you need a full IDE with current Groovy support, I would look at [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), [the Groovy plugin for Eclipse](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Eclipse+Plugin), or [STS](http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts)

Comment: thanks. I've been using STS/Eclipse, but I just find the groovy support to be really flaky at times. There are frequent errors when formatting code, organizing imports, code completion, etc. I understand a lot of that is because groovy is dynamic, but still, it can be annoying. I haven't tried the IntelliJ support yet (mostly because IntelliJ's free version has some limitations), but maybe it's time. Thanks.

Comment: No worries, it's a real shame about Netbeans, as at one time it was way out in front with Groovy support.  Then it all stopped, and its now horribly out of date :-/  Hopefully someone at Oracle will make it a priority again ;-)  Good luck!

Comment: AFAIK there are no limitations to the Groovy support in the free version of IntelliJ. However, it does not have Grails support. I have tried all 3 IDEs, and IntelliJ is miles ahead of the competition